# python : use elements from a list as keys to a dictionary in order of list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

```
my_lst = ['b','c','a']
dict = {}
for i in my_lst[]:
    dict[i] = []
print dict
# prints: => {'c': [], 'b': [], 'a': []}
```

How can i get dict to be `{'b': [ ], 'c': [ ], 'a': [ ]}`
with the keys in a similar order as in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> my_lst = ['b','c','a']
>>> D = OrderedDict()
>>> for i in my_lst:
...     D[i] = []
>>> D
OrderedDict([('b', []), ('c', []), ('a', [])])
>>> print D.items()
[('b', []), ('c', []), ('a', [])]
```